# Custom sidebar on category pages

Tags: categories, sidebar

On my website I've two category pages, one called "agenda" and the other "artículos". I've set theme on the main menu:

https://institutoschuman.org/

I'd like to have different sidebar for each one of this category pages. Unfortunately my theme doesn't let me to do this. Is there a way to do that without installing many plugins? Or, is there only one plugin that let me to do that?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

one way to accomplish your goal would be to create a child theme (https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). You create a folder inside `/wp-content/themes/`, then add a `style.css` file inside it with a few comment lines at the top to tell WordPress this is a child theme of whatever your current theme is.

Sample `style.css` file: all you need to do is change `parent-theme-folder-name` to whatever your original theme folder is. So for example if you are currently using Twenty Sixteen, change `parent-theme-folder-name` below to `twenty-sixteen`.

```
/*
Theme Name: Custom category sidebars
Version: 1.0
Template: parent-theme-folder-name
*/
```

Next, to create your new sidebars, create a blank `functions.php` inside your child theme folder, and add:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add custom sidebars for categories
 */

// Agenda Category Sidebar
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'          => 'Agenda sidebar',
    'id'            => 'agenda-sidebar',
    'description'   => 'Agenda category sidebar'
));

// Articulos Category Sidebar
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'          => 'Articulos sidebar',
    'id'            => 'articulos-sidebar',
    'description'   => 'Articulos category sidebar'
));
```

Finally, create a blank `category-agenda.php` file and a blank `category-articulos.php` file. Copy and paste your original theme's `category.php` code right into those files. Then, look for the sidebar portion, and change the part where it calls the sidebar:

Again in this example just change `sidebar-slug` to your new slug: in `category-agenda.php` change it to `agenda-sidebar`, and in `category-articulos.php` change it to `articulos-sidebar`.

Once all these files are created and uploaded, activate your child theme and set up the widgets in the sidebars however you like.

Comment: It should be noted that the `Template:` value in the style.css file of a child theme should match the **folder name** of the parent theme.